# Blender crashes in Cycles viewport

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have very frequent crashes. I noticed they come as soon as I am using Cycles and one of theese things : ocean modifier, displacement, complex shaders, volumetrics, and complex geometry in general. The crash occurs randomly while tweaking a setting or adding a node. Not during render, allways in rendered shading in the viewport.

I use the latest drivers.

I tried other blender versions :

-2.90 portable version : less frequent crashes but still a big issue to properly work

-2.83 version : less frequent than portable version but still an issue to work

---

Some infos:

Render properties > Performance > Persistent image : unchecked

System > Render devices > CUDA > CPU (it is what I found worked best)

No viewport denoising

---

My setup :

CPU : AMD Ryzen 9 3900x threadripper 12core 3.8GHz

GPU : Nvidia RTX 2070 SUPER ( with latest Studio driver)

RAM : 32 Go

Windows 10

Blender 2.90.1

---

Please help !

Comment: 2.90.1 has some crashing issues with GPU viewport denoise and render. This is being fixed for 2.91 (coming out by the end of the month)

Comment: In System > Render Devices and choosing OptiX, still gives you crashes? As the user above said, have you tried disabling viewport denoising? In your temp folder you might be able to find a file with the name of your .blend but ending in .crash.txt, you might find the reason for the crash (Also, the Ryzen 9 3900x is not a threadripper)

Comment: As said in description I use no viewport denoising. Tried OptiX and still have the crashes. Should I change it in Render Properties > Device > GPU ? I don't get why there are two places to change this setting. (my bad for the non threadripper :p)
I found crashlogs but can't understand them really.